# GIT checkout - почему мерджит?

Tags: git

Изучаю Git.

Поясните, почему мерджит ветки, хотя поидее должно просто переключать?

И как в этом случае сделать чтобы просто переключало ветки без мерджа?

1. Создаю ветку из dev и перехожу в нее

   `git checkout -b newbranch`
2. Делаю там измения в файлах
3. Перключаю текущую ветку на dev

   `git checkout dev`

В результате оно мерджит newbranch в dev

```
root@root:/var/www/myproject# git checkout dev
M   src/public/css/custom.css
M   src/src/Controller/AbTest/AbTestController.php
M   src/templates/ab_test/index.html.twig
Переключено на ветку «dev»
Ваша ветка обновлена в соответствии с «origin/dev».
```

Comment: Возможно оно не мержит, а кладёт в stash изменения перед переключением веток и достаёт оттуда после переключения. Если это так, то вам надо или закоммитить изменения в новой ветке или вручную положить их в `stash` перед переключением веток, переключить ветку и не доставать изменения из `stash`. Скорее всего вам будет проще и удобнее изменения закоммитить перед переключением веток.

Comment: Между 2 и 3 не хватает шага: делаю коммит

Comment: спасибо разобрался. Надо коммитить всегда перед чекаутом

Answer (score 3):

Оно не мерджит. Буква "М" перед названием файла переводится как "Modified". Программа вас предупреждает, что файлы изменены, но ничего не мерджит.

Comment: Ясно. Но иногда оно запрещает переходить назад на dev либо другую ветку с которой создавалась ветка, и пишет - "сделайте сначала коммит". А иногда переходит и перезатирает файлы как раз этим "Modified". Видимо Modified делает тогда, когда файлы(которые изменены в текущей ветке) не закоммичены были в той ветке куда делается переход.
В общем надо коммитить всегда при переходе, если есть цель избежать перезатираний.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы написали в ответах "надо коммитить всегда перед чекаутом".

Иногда коммитить неудобно (например, нет уверенности, что правки для коммита - корректные). Тогда можно "отложить" правки - погуглите про команды git stash, git stash list, git stash apply.